# Phonegap installations

Tags: android, node.js, git, cordova

I tried to installed **Phonegap** .
So I ran the command in command prompt

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

But it throws the error like **GIT** not found but I have already installed **GIT**.

Please suggest on the below error. Thanks in advance.

```
C:\Users\bellamks>npm install -g phonegap

npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git

npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed using git. npm ERR! This is most likely not a
problem with npm itself. npm ERR! Please check if you have git
installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bellamks\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: What happens if you type `git` and hit enter on the command line?

Comment: C:\Users\bellamks>git
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Check whether `git` executable path exists in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: C:\Users\bellamks>npm install -g phonegap
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config -
-get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)

Comment: Please some one help on this ,Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add git to your PATH is to uncompress (anywhere you want) [`PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe).

Add `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit\bin` to your `%PATH%`. (see "[Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/6309)")

Comment: while instaling the phoegap got the this error  please help on this "error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line"

Comment: @Sreeni But first, did my suggestion helped resolved the original question (the issue about git)? If yes, please accept the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), and make a new question.

Comment: I am very ..new for git and node.js. but i wanted to do the phonegap installation in my pc. it is very urgent for me .could you please help on this issue .

Comment: C:\Users\bellamks>npm install -g phonegap

Comment: npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bellamks\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\bellamks>

Comment: @Sreeni one question at a time: close this one (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer, if git is now recognized), and open a new question, where you can detail your setup and your commands. More people will be able to help that way.

Comment: Git working fine, after run this command got the error=>error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line"

Comment: @Sreeni Exactly, that is why I suggests to close (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this question, and start a new one, more visible for everybody.