# Error in using gcloud init

Tags: git, shell, gcloud

Im trying to clone my cloud repository to a local git repository 
I run the

```
gcloud auth login
```

but when running

```
gcloud init cognitusonlinecourses
```

[image]

any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `C:\Program Files\Google\GCloud` [is in your `%PATH%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/6309), a better course of action would be:

```
 cd c:\my\path\to\en\empty\folder
 gcloud init cognitusonlinecourses
```

That would avoid trying to do operations directly in `C:\Program Files\Google\GCloud`.

The [OP Ahmad Hijazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4038204/ahmad-hijazi) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022977/error-in-using-gcloud-init/32023247?noredirect=1#comment51975137_32023247) that trying the same command *outside* of C:\Program Files works.
But it requires Git: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32022378/6309).

Comment: I changed the path to an empty folder C:\Program Files\Google\empty
but the same error..

Comment: @AhmadHijazi could you please use a path which is *not* in `C:\Program Files`? Like `c:\test\` Create it the folder first.

Comment: aha okay worked !
But another error appears , they are telling me that ERROR:cannot find git  . please install git and try again .
And already I installed it , maybe there is something to do after installing it?!

Comment: @AhmadHijazi yes, uncompress https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe in C:\Git (create C:\Git first), and add C:\Git\bin to your PATH. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/6309)

Comment: when I added it ( set PATH=C:\Git\bin ) then after executing the command gcloud init cognitusonlinecourses ; the result is 'gcloud' is not recognized as an internal ..

Comment: @AhmadHijazi Sure: ad gcloud in your PATH as well (that is add `C:\Program Files\Google\cloud SDK` to your PATH)

Comment: its not workingggg, im very sry
PLEASE CHECK THE PHOTO I EDITED IN MY QUESTION , and tell me which command must I type!

Comment: @AhmadHijazi that is because you replace the *entire* PATH with gcloud and git. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/6309: you are supposed to add to your PATH, not replace it. Try to do so in a new CMD windows.

Comment: worked thank you , still when I'm pushing to Cloud Repository using : git push -u origin master /// the result is : src refspec master does not match any. ?

Comment: @AhmadHijazi that would be best presented in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Typically gcloud installation paths end with `\bin`.  I don't know exactly how gcloud is installed in your machine, but I would expect something like the following to work:

> set PATH=C:\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\bin

The directory you're looking for should include the file `gcloud.cmd`.